# Sandbox renewal of subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am making subscription in the sandbox pay-pal and i just want to know how you guys do for the renew of subscription...example if the customers subscription is expired how can i let him renew his/her subscription do i need to create another button for the subscription just to renew his/her subscription?just what i did in his/her first subscription...and how do i reset the date so that his ending date of subscription will be lesser so that i can test to renew the subscription in the sandbox pay-pal.

Or how do i redirect my customers to my sandbox test(business) site if they're subscriptions are expired.what should i do?...please let me know how to do this.

just like in there first subscription they redirected to my sandbox test site and they can see how much they would pay...

I appreciated much more reply.

Thank you.

Comment: Can anyone give a hand on this please...I am still beginner on this.

Comment: How do i redirect my customer whose subscriptions are expired to my sandbox test site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using IPN, PayPal sends an IPN post when a subscription is created, a payment is made, and when it expires. You can use that IPN post to trigger a script to send your buyers an e-mail. That e-mail can include a link to your site where the button is located or a link the buyers can click to be redirected to PayPal and resubscribe from there.

There isn't a guaranteed way to have buyers return to your site after their subscription expires. Sending them an e-mail with their different options and an explanation that their subscription has expired is a fair way of handling the situation.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply...I've been waiting for this help,...about the subscription button can i still use this button that i had created in their subscription,or there is a renewal button for this....about the redirected and resubscribe i don't know the url to open in my test site in paypal sandbox...

Comment: There is a variable called "modify" you can include in your Subscription buttons that determines whether or not the buyer can use the button to create a new Subscription or renew an existing one. Set the value to "1" and buyers can sign up for a new Subscription if they don't already have one and resubscribe if they do already have a Subscription with you.

Comment: Hi PayPal_Patrick,I do it this way In my first subscription button it has no modify variable,then i created another subscription button with the variable modify="1" is this okay ?...then problem that i encountered is that when i tried to renewsubscription with the same amount and the same terms of billing it will generate error this is the error "We are unable to modify your subscription because the new terms are the same as the old terms."...what does it means? please help me on this thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the error generated cause by attempting to renew the subscription even the subscription is not yet ended..because i test to susbscribe example july 19-2013 - july 19-2014,then after that i tried to renesusbscription just to test,then when i click the button having the same amount and terms. the error shows up after i log-in my personal or buyers email in sandbox-paypal...please enligthen my mind.

Comment: The answer doesn't give the solution. I am also working a subscription project. In my sandbox account, I find there are several subscription profiles are expired and canceled. Then, when I try to update the subscription, I get the error message as well. I guess only Active subscription profile can be modified.